# Action on a elements in Hover state

Tags: html, css, wordpress, hover, footer

I have a hover problem inside [My Site's footer](http://accountabletest.com/). As you can see, every link inside the footer (tweets too) change to white on hover, but also **move**. **I just don't need any of them to move at all.**I don't know how to stop this action.

CSS code:

```
#footer a {
font-size: 14px;
font-family: 'Oswald', Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
color: #fec214;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this another selector:

```
#sidebar ul li, #footer ul li :hover{
    padding: 0px 0 0px 0;
    margin: 0px 4px 10px 0px;   
    line-height: 34px;
    background: none;
    font-size: 1em; 
    padding-top: 17px;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
    color: white;
    width: 200px;
}
```

That triggers the `hover` state for `a` items too inside `li`. And has more [specificity](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/).

If you remove the `line-height` declaration then stops the move:

```
line-height: 34px; /*Remove this*/
```

Comment: Hi @Danko, I've removed the line-height declaration, but the movement persists. Should I separate the #sidebar class and the #footer class hovers? . I did notice that if I change the line-height from 34px to 15px the movement effect is shorter, but still remains. In mozilla this change from 34px to 20px would remain as if nothing has happened in the footer's first column. Could this line-height be linked with the same element's line-height with no hover state declared?

Comment: Have you clear your cache? and upload that change to your site so I can check?

Comment: Cache is cleared and the mentioned change is live @Danko

Comment: @Gonpires I say remove the line but if you want to keep it set it the same as the a  `#footer .widgetBox a` here is 16px

Comment: 16px works perfectly on Chrome and safari ! , but I need to make it work also in mozilla. Do you have any idea for this?

Comment: Then just kepp this selector off that declaration `#footer ul li :hover{` and make a new one with `line-height:normal` or without it @Gonpires

Comment: I've just written `#footer ul li :hover{ line-height:normal}` But no luck. (even the footer icons move now on mozilla) I'm using media queries for this cross browser site. Could this help in some way? @Danko

Comment: @Gonpires Is not so difficult just remove the declaration for lineheight on that selector there is no need to modify that property on hover

Comment: Please notice that I've removed it when you told me to. But mozilla does not seem to care. `#sidebar ul li, #footer ul li :hover{
 padding: 0px 0 0px 0;
 margin: 0px 4px 10px 0px; 
 background: none;
 font-size: 1em; 
 padding-top: 17px;
 margin-bottom: -20px;
 color: white;
 width: 200px;

}`

Comment: @Gonpires I have checked right now and works fine for me in mozilla wihte the line-heigth normal press ctrl r to reload the page and avoid cache

Comment: I've added line-height: normal, once again. Cleared cache, reloaded, icons are still moving, as well as links. Then removed and tried everything again. Still no luck at all. I appreciate your help really, If you got any other idea let me know, in the mean time I'll keep trying.

Comment: I've solved it. I copied the structure I had on the third column and now it works. The line-height help helped me as a guide. Thanks!

Comment: Didn`t mean to. Sorry about that.Have a good day.(You did answered first, just for the record, great support was also given from @Esser). Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

I checked your CSS and this is what I found

```
media="screen"
#sidebar ul li, #footer ul li :hover {
padding: 0px 0 0px 0;
margin: 0px 4px 10px 0px;
line-height: 34px;
background: none;
font-size: 1em;
padding-top: 17px;
margin-bottom: -20px;
color: white;
width: 200px;
}
```

There you go. just remove the `color:white;` and the `line-height` and then you should be good to go.

Comment: what's up? I did remove it, but I still have the problem. I've changed line-height from 34px to 15px and the movement is less noticeable, but persists. (only in chrome and safari, not mozilla).

Comment: You need to add a jsfiddle so we can see what's going on. (or at least update it on your actual website.) Have you tried to remove the `padding-top` too? Try to disable the whole code block `/* */` and take it from there.

Comment: I changed line-height to 16px and no more movement on safari and chrome, but the problem persists only on the first column, in Mozilla (browser support needed). I tried removing padding-top, but no change. I'd love to add a jsfiddle but my site is under a wordpress architecture and when I copy the html and css, it renders just a box.

Comment: You need to at least update it online so I can see it. It's impossible to know the problem without seeing it.

Comment: It's Updated. You can see how every footer icon and links are moving in mozilla.

Comment: Apparently it's not updated. I checked it in chrome and the line height and color are still there.

Comment: Please take a look @Esser `#sidebar ul li, #footer ul li :hover{ padding: 0px 0 0px 0; margin: 0px 4px 10px 0px;  background: none; font-size: 1em;  padding-top: 17px; margin-bottom: -20px; color: white; width: 200px; }`  Color white is needed, that's why remains.

Comment: You have a few issues here. disable one at a time and check it out. you have bottom margin twice. once it's 10px then it's -20px. and you didn't remove the padding-top

Comment: Now I've edited it, but still same thing.  `#sidebar ul li, #footer ul li :hover{
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 margin: 0px 4px -20px 0px; 
 background: none;
 font-size: 1em; 
 color: white;
 width: 200px;

}` I noticed that the code on the third footer's column doesn't move so I'll try to copy that structure on the other columns.

Comment: It doesn't happen in the third column because they're not links. It's still not updated online so I can't work with it

Comment: Yes they are,` <a href="#">FOLLOW US ON TWITTER</a>`

Comment: I've solved it. I copied the structure I had on the third column and now it works. thank u for your help.

Comment: Hey bro, an upvote requires 15exp, Im still a new user, imagine that I thought I could validate two answers LOL. The validated answer replied first, although you also were helping me, that's why I mentioned it. But that's how valdiation goes along apparently. Believe me Im really grateful for your help and I would validate your ans too If it were possible. Next time I'll stick to one user to avoid this type of funny issues. Take it easy, thank u.

Comment: Guess what? You can now upvote! You have a 17 reputation. Neat!

Comment: U to buddy!! See ya around

Answer (score 0):

You have a line-height property in a selector which fires on hovering over your links and moves them around.
Just remove it, and see if it work for you.

```
#sidebar ul li, #footer ul li :hover{
    padding: 0px 0 0px 0;
    margin: 0px 4px 10px 0px;   
    /* line-height: 34px; */
    background: none;
    font-size: 1em; 
    padding-top: 17px;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
    color: white;
    width: 200px;
}
```

This snippet is from line 2603 in your [style.css](http://accountabletest.com/wp-content/themes/hardy/style.css).

Comment: Hey @Michael S., I've removed it, but the movement persists. I've changed the line-height from 34px to 15px and the movement is smaller (just in chrome and safari, not in mozilla).